# BlankCordovaApp1 build error

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I installed visual studio 2013 community edition, and created a "JavaScript -> Apache Cordova Apps" named BlankCordovaApp1 using template, and didn't change any code.

When I build for Device|Debug|Android, Output window shows:
(I also tried to build for other platform, got same error.)

```html
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  c:\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.0 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\5QZQI2Q0.RU2\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.70
1>  ------ Current globally installed version: 0.1.70
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I didn't see any error but a warning, and Chrome also didn't show any project page.

My environment:
Windows 7 Enterprise, Service Pack 1
Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, Update 4
Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3
Chrome 40.0.2214.115 m

Comment: Do you have an android device connected to your machine?  If you set the build output to diagnostic (Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\Build and Run\MSBuild project build output verbosity) and do a clean build, you will get more useful information that might identify why it failed.

Comment: As Ellen suggested, does not look like you have device connected.  To debug Android on device requires additional setup.  See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: The documentation and processes for this package are a little rough yet.  You will need to combine information from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771545.aspx), Phonegap Platform Guides (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides), and the developer sites (http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html and https://developer.apple.com/) to work out how it will all work together.

Comment: Post the error messages from Error List window to investigate further

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue here. Were you able to sort that out? @Abhishek-MSFT in my case there is no error on the Error List. It just fails to compile without showing any error even on the Output.

Answer (score 1):

Update VS Tools for Cordova to the latest version (0.3.2 as of today), and you will see the error in the Output or Error List window.

Otherwise go to `%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\vs-mda` and edit `vs-cli.cmd` as follows:

```sh
node "%~dp0\app.js" %* > vs-mda.log 2> vs-mda-err.log
```

This will dump build logs to these files in your project folder.

Comment: Hi @herman I'm having the same issue here and I did this changes you suggested. These logs are not generated. I've searched for vs-mda.log and vs-mda-err.log in my entire machine and not a single file was generated! If I just run the vs-cli.cmd it generates both files on the vs-cli directory pointing that there was a problem loading the project (as expected). But they aren't generated while using Visual Studio.

Comment: @RafaelMerlin, from you post above I see you have already figured that out.

Comment: @HermanKan Thanks now I can investigate the error, why don't they show this in out put window in vs2013?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem this way:

First I had to go to Tools, Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run and changed MsBuild project build output to Detailed.

After that I went to Cordova Tools (still inside options) and cleared the cache.

When I tried to build my project again I was able to check a massive output showing the errors, I read through most of it and there was an alert telling me that npm couldn't connect to the internet, probably because of the company proxy.

Since I don't need to set my proxy or its password I tried only to disable SSL on npm by doing this:

```
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

And it worked really well.

Maybe if you need to change your proxy you can try something like this:

```
npm config set proxy http://my.proxy.com:1234
npm config set https-proxy http://my.proxy.com:1234
```

I hope it helps.

EDIT: When I tried to download plugins I couldn't so I had to add my proxy using the above lines and them it all worked (both the running the app + the plugin downloading).