# Cordova app Build is failing in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am not able to build cordova app in Visual studio. i have installed cordova extensions for my visual studio

In VS console it just displaying build is failed but no errors.

> ------ Build started: Project: SampleCordovaUsingCTP, Configuration: Debug Android ------
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
>   1>  GeneratedJavascript=
>   1>  C:\PhonegapSamples\SampleCordovaUsingCTP\SampleCordovaUsingCTP\SampleCordovaUsingCTP>call "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
>   1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.29 (x64) and npm.
>   1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R3EFQQ33.L3R\packages\vs-mda
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Can you post the diagnostic build log. Go to Tools --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> Build and Run, change MSBuild project "Build Output Verbosity" to Diagnostic. 
Rebuild the project and post the text from output window.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848548/blankcordovaapp1-build-error.